# input type=checkbox indeterminate state is not visualized when using google external css

Tags: javascript, css

Im developing google sheet side bar and using google addon css.

I want to display checkbox with indeterminate state, but the addon prevent it.
See the code snippet for illustration.
**With link to google**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
        With google css
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cond1">indeterminate checkbox
        </label><br>
      
        <span id="span" style="font-weight: bold;">With google css</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         //Set indeterminate 
            document.getElementById("cond1").indeterminate = true;
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Without**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">   -->
    </head>
    <body>
        Without google css
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cond1">indeterminate checkbox
        </label><br>
      
        <span id="span" style="font-weight: bold;">With google css</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         //Set indeterminate 
            document.getElementById("cond1").indeterminate = true;
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google CSS has `appearance: none;`... Override it with `appearance: auto !important;` when it is not checked.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  appearance: auto !important;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
  appearance: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
        With google css
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cond1">indeterminate checkbox
        </label><br>
      
        <span id="span" style="font-weight: bold;">With google css</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         //Set indeterminate 
            document.getElementById("cond1").indeterminate = true;
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```